# Issue with group by in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, group-by, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to group by the first element of an array in my documents.

And then filter so I only get groups with a value larger than 1. I am looking for duplicates.

The documents look like this:

```json
    {
        "Entity": {
            "EntityId": 118788,
            "Urls": [
                {
                    Value: "http://some/url"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

This query works fine:

```sql
SELECT c.Entity.Urls[0]["Value"] as url, count(1) as cnt
FROM c
where IS_DEFINED(c.Entity.Urls) AND ARRAY_LENGTH(c.Entity.Urls) > 0
group by c.Entity.Urls[0]["Value"]
```

But how do I filter my groups to only get those where cnt > 1?
Or alternatively sort by cnt descending.

The following is giving me an error:

```sql
select * from 
(
    SELECT c.Entity.Urls[0]["Value"] as url, count(1) as cnt
    FROM c
    where IS_DEFINED(c.Entity.Urls) AND ARRAY_LENGTH(c.Entity.Urls) > 0
    group by c.Entity.Urls[0]["Value"]
) 
where cnt > 1
```

Comment: *The following is giving me an error*: which error? Please share the entire error message;

Comment: `count` might be a reserved word in CosmosDB; did you try changing that alias to something else, say `cnt`?

Comment: `count()` is a reserved function name (as is `value` which you have already worked around, with bracket notation). That aside: you really shouldn't be depending on any type of array ordering in your data model. Also: in your array, why have a `"value"` key when there is only one property (you can have a scalar array of url's)? Please edit to show your error, as well as expected output. It's unclear why you're querying the way you are

Comment: thanks for feedback. My initial "group by" is working fine. It seems to be ok to use count as an alias. But I have also tried to replace it. Same result. I didn't design the structure of the document. And I am unable to change it. But again. The group by is working fine.
I am using the Data Explorer in azure portal web ui. I don't really see any relevant details in the error messages. I just have: "Failed to query item for container <container name>: One of the input values is invalid."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
select  *  from
(
SELECT c.Entity.Urls[0]["Value"] as  url, count(1) as cnt
FROM c
where IS_DEFINED(c.Entity.Urls) AND ARRAY_LENGTH(c.Entity.Urls) >  0
group  by c.Entity.Urls[0]["Value"]
) c where c.cnt>1
```

Here you need to give a name to the result of group by query to access the column.
I have given `c` to the result of first query and used as  `c.cnt` while doing query.

[image]